# Error al cargar datos vacíos en datatablejs

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables, datatable

Estoy trabajando en un sistema web en el cual tengo que mostrar datos en una tabla, estos datos lo traigos de una url propia, al mostrarlos mediante ajax en datatable funciona bien, el problema radica en cuando la respuesta no retorna datos, sea por que no hay incidencias en la base de datos para esa consulta, me genera el siguiente mensaje de error, el mensaje es entendible que suceda ya que lo que me retorna es null, pero no he podido controlarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:

```
function modal_list_ofert(id) {
   $("#vh").val(id);
   var table = $("#example4").DataTable({
     destroy: true,
     responsive: true,
     ajax: {
       method: "post",
       url: base_url + "admin/oferta/lts",
       dataType: "json",
       data: { id: id },
       dataSrc: function (params) {
          console.log(params.Mens);
          return params.Mens;
       },
     },
     columns: [
            { data: "ID" },
            { data: "ACT" },
            { data: "CANT" },
            { data: "NOM" },
            { data: "TEL" },
            { data: "EMA" },
            { data: "ID_VH" },
            { data: "OF_G" },
     ],
    });
   $("#list-ofert").modal();
  }
```

Mi respuesta json es la siguiente:

```
'error': false, 'Mens': {ID: "4", ACT: "1", CANT: "8888888", NOM: "prubea", TEL: "98989898", EMA: "pruebaa@paa.com"}
```

Mi respuesta negativa en caso de no tener datos es `{'error': true}`

Para esta respuesta la genero mediante php, el cual es el siguiente:

```
$data = array('error' => false, 'Mens' => $list_ofert);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Siendo `$list_ofert` mi array con la respuesta afirmativa.

Como puedo evitar que este mensaje de error siga saliendo???

Otra cosa es que tambien quiero implementar estos botones en la tabla, como podría hacerlo mediante esta misma respuesta ajax?? Estos botones tendría su funcionalidad basada en el id que trae los datos, como podría implementarlos??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué haces en PHP cuando no hay datos para mostrar? Deberías retornar  datos en el mismo formato para evitar ese mensaje, por ejemplo: `echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'Mens' => array()));`, Error en falso y un arreglo vacío. Para los botones, mejor crea una nueva pregunta y asegúrate de incluir un ejemplo [completo, mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Cuando no hay datos, la respuesta php es ```'error': ture```, si se me paso por alto este

Comment: ¿Se solucionó el problema?

Comment: No, aun nada, sigue presentando

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que *DataTable* espera recibir datos y, si no están disponibles, debes modificar el origen:

```
"dataSrc": function(params){
    // Si hay error y es verdadero o no existe .Mens
    if(params.error || !params.Mens){
        // Devolver arreglo vacío
        return [];
    } else {
        return params.Mens;
    }
}
```

Si hay error, devuelves un arreglo vacío, de lo contrario, devuelves los registros encontrados.

Créditos: [Foro de DataTable](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38847/json-ajax-error-when-trying-to-load-an-empty-table-from-database-through-mysqli-query)